# how to stop/recheck data in forEach using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I want to check my data coming from database whether its available or not .
I am using for each function to loop through it but currently its not checking its running simultaneously.

on running simultaneously its sending enormous messages to my channel.

How can i check after each loop whether data are present or not?
Any help here would be very much thankful.

## Mycode

```
 con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("query for getting results", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var results = result;

        var results = result;
        var found = false;
        if (typeof results != "undefined" && results != null && results.length != null && results.length > 0){
            results.forEach ( row => {

                //codes to execute
                //How can i check after each loop over the results whther its available or not?
            });
            
        }
        else{
            console.log("hello");
        }
        

    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please post a minimal amount of code, just enough to show your issue? There seems to be a lot there that is not relevant for your question.

Comment: @trincot will update .

Comment: @trincot updated please check.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is? You iterate over the result set and then want to know whether "it is available or not". I don't understand what you mean by that. What would `row` be if you consider it "not available"?

Comment: @trincot my worry lies on after one execution it should check whether result set is satisfied or not then again it will loop. but in my case its continuously running.

Comment: are you performing any operation on result set at //codes to execute line ??

Comment: @GaneshKarewad this is resolved by using timeInterval